# Liquid markup: do not display if paramaters a and b and c are not set

Tags: liquid

```
{% unless site.param1 or site.param2 or site.param3 %}
 <p>Hello!</p>
{% endunless %}
```

In a Jekyll (Github Pages) site, I'm trying to make 'Hello!' only appear if any one or more of these parameters are set, and not appear if none are set.

The code above does not appear to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% if site.param1 or site.param2 or site.param3 %}
 <p>Hello!</p>
{% endif %}
```

It seems it's a simple logic issue, not a Liquid issue. I [rubber duck debugged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) my own question by asking it.